# How convert ToList method to LINQ expression

Tags: c#, linq

```
    List<string> ToList(string[] names)
    {
        List<string> l = new List<string>();

        foreach (string n in names)
        {
            l.Add(n.ToUpper());
            l.Add(n.ToLower());
        }
        return l;
    }
```

How convert ToList method to LINQ expression(method syntax).
 Any help much appreciated.
 Thanks.

Comment: Why do you call `l.Add()` twice? It seems like you just want something like `names.Select(n => n.ToLower()).ToList()`, but it's hard to say for sure given such a vaguely-worded question.

Comment: typing error, sorry.

Comment: why don't u just import System.Linq and use the native method? Giving an array of strings called names you can use the method array.ToList(). It will give you a List of strings with all the values from the array

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
names.SelectMany(x => new[] { x.ToLower(), x.ToUpper() }).ToList()
```